# Connect to SQL Server using python from Raspberry pi

Tags: python, sql-server, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database using python.I have followed,
http://blog.tryolabs.com/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/

I have used following Python code to connect with the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 with above setting.

```
  import pyodbc
  user='sa'
  password='PC#1234'
  database='climate'
  port='1433'
  TDS_Version='8.0'
  server='192.168.1.146'
  con_string= 'UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;PORT=%s;TDS=%s;SERVER=%s;' %
  (user,password, database,port,TDS_Version,server)
  cnxn=pyodbc.connect(con_string)
  cursor=cnxn.cursor()
  cursor.execute("select * from mytable")
  row=cursor.fetchone()
  print row
```

I got following error,

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "sql.py", line 15, in <module>
cnxn=pyodbc.connect(con_string)
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source
 name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I also have installed pymssql and tried to connect to SQL Server. For this I have used following python code,

```
   import pymssql
   connection=pymssql.connect(user='sa',password='PC#1234',
   host='192.168.1.146',database='climate',as_dict=True)
   cursor=connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute('select * from mytable;')
   rows=cursor.fetchall()
```

I have got following error,

```
    connection=pymssql.connect(user='sa',password='PC#1234',
    host='192.168.1.146',database='climate',as_dict=True)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pymssql.py", line 607, in connect
       raise OperationalError, e[0]
    pymssql.OperationalError: DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
    Net-Lib error during Operation now in progress Error 115 
    - Operation now in progress
```

what is the reason for showing data source name not found and adaptive server is not available?

Comment: The first message says you didn't specify which driver to use. ODBC is a protocol for connecting to any database, it can't work unless you specify a driver. Your code does *not* match the sample, which uses a configuration file and passes it to the connection string. In that file, the driver is FreeTDS